# Twitter Bootstrap and Spring MVC

Tags: spring, twitter-bootstrap, spring-mvc

Good morning!
I'm considering using Twitter Bootstrap with Spring MVC.
My question is this: do not just import the Bootstrap file and declare them in different file jsp?

Because looking at the following page https://samerabdelkafi.wordpress.com/2014/09/17/bootstrap-3/ you see how they are injected dependencies bootstrap and jquery (jar file):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
    <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.0</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
    <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

And then forced the resource handler for / webjars / ** to associate it with the classpath: / META-INF / resources / webjars / located in the bootstrap-3.2.0.jar:

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.mycompany.myproject.web.controller" })
public class MvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/webjars/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/");
    }
.................
```

}

Jsp page there will be references to bootstrap:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='webjars/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css'>
</head>
<body>

    <!-- YOUR CODE HERE -->

<script type="text/javascript" src="webjars/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="webjars/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Concluding my question is this: **what path should be taken to add to a project Bootstrap Spring MVC?**

thanks

Comment: I'd go without webjars. But again, it's my personal opinion. I don't like my client side dependencies packages as jars (Don't want to add an additional layer that is not really required).

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if it fully answers Your question, it's just my personal opinion (mostly based on dealing with external **Dandelion Datatables** library in addition to Bootstrap), but I do not like webjars at all. It's because very often modern JavaScript libraries often tries to handle dependencies on their own and webjars can be a little confusing there. There can be situation when You declare something in webjars and out of the sudden - application tries to download libraries from CDN or other web page.

What is more important to add newer version of the library You have to perform (in Your situation) additional Maven build. It's sometimes an overkill when You just want to switch to eg. minimised version. But it's just my personal opinion.